# Behat: How do you use multiline values in tables?

Tags: behat

How do you use multiline values in tables?

Pystring dont work

```
| single | multi
| qewr   | """
           qewrqewr
           qwerqre
           """
```

This doesnt either

```
| single | multi
| qewr   | qewrqewr
         | qwerqre
```

I want to use a scenario outline and seed a form with input multiple times, not having multilines would be a bugger.

Comment: Why don't you just put each line into a new section of the table? I don't think this is supported by Behat, and it's probably not supported by Cucumber either. 

Alternatively, you could try placing a `\n` wherever there is a line break.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "," in your tables. For example:

```
  | single | multi    |
  | one    | one, two |
```

If you use TableNode extension, check your extension Gherkin.
It possible need upgrade.
https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/99

I hope that was helpful, though a bit late.